# Trying to run a container on docker but can not access the website of the application we created

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

We've been using python3 and Docker as our framework. Our main issue is that while we try to run the docker container it redirects us to the browser but the website can not be reached. But it is working when we run the commands `python manage.py runserver` manualy from the terminal of VS code

here is the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "2.12.2"

services:
web:
tty: true
build:
dockerfile: Dockerfile
context: .
command: bash -c "cd happy_traveller && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 "
ports:
\- 8000:8000
restart: always
```

the docker file

```
FROM  python:3.10
EXPOSE 8000
WORKDIR /
COPY happy_traveller .
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
```

and the app structure

```
|_App_Folder
      |_happy_traveller
            |_API
            |_paycache
            |_core
            |_settings
            |_templates
            |_folder
            |_folder
            |_folder
            |_manage.py
       |_dockerfile
       |_docker-compose.yml
       |_requirements.txt
       |_readmme.md
       |_get-pip.py
```

We would really apreciate the help. thank you for your time

Comment: Since it is relevant for the question: is that the actual structure of the `docker-compose.yml`? If not: please [edit] the post and correct it.

Comment: You are copying `happy_traveller` folder in your docker file, why do you need to change the directory again before running the server with this command, `"cd happy_traveller && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 "`? I think you should just add command `"python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 "` and it will work

Comment: On top of that: `COPY . .` seems pointless since we have already copied the content of `happy_traveler` to `.`.

Answer (score 1):

As you copied the source folder(`happy_traveller`) in your `docker` file, you don't need to run the `cd` command again, so the `docker-compose` file would look like this:

```
version: "2.12.2"

services:
  web:
    tty: true
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    command: bash -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 "
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    restart: always
```

Comment: the `docker.compose.yml` is missing formatting. Also, the `\` in `\- 8000:8000` seems off

Comment: code formatter for yml will fix it, I just showed how the commands look like